# How to reset state of DataTable defined with filters or/and search field, with PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, cookies, datatables

Working on PHP application, that uses DataTables (https://datatables.net) on several layouts.

Can I somehow reset all DataTable's filters and search data, after end user logged out from application? In other words, to clear all cookies that DataTables library created, if it's possible with PHP functions..

Main idea is to reset application to it's main state after user is logged out from application.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You would do this in JQuery, not PHP, using [destroy()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy%28%29).  You would then initialize a new datatable instance.

Comment: Nope, I have to reset it with PHP somehow...

Comment: Good luck with that.  PHP is server side and is "done" once the page renders.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says: (https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html)

> The built in state saving method uses the HTML5 localStorage and
>   sessionStorage APIs for efficient storage of the data.

It means you cannot reach it with PHP.
However you can change the storage of filter parameters to cookie or server side.

> Alternative options of using cookies or saving the state on the server
>   hrough Ajax can be used through the stateSaveCallback and
>   stateLoadCallback options.

You should write code which:
- save the filter parameters to cookie what you can remove on logout with PHP
or
- save the filter parameters to database via AJAX and you also can remove it on logout with PHP

example is here:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone out there is interested in a solution to this:
As some people rightly pointed out, there's no way to delete localStorage from PHP because PHP works ***only*** on the server and localStorage is client-based. 
However, a way to achieve what OP wants is make sure that the page shown after logout has the JS needed to delete localStorage. For example, say that after logout, the user gets redirected to *comebacksoon.php*; what you need is to make sure that in the html of this *comebacksoon* page, you include:

```
<script>
  localStorage.removeItem(keyYouWantToDelete);
</script>
```

It should be noted that if the user closes the window before *comebacksoon.php* is loaded, localStorage won't be deleted, but this approach has worked for me in most cases.